# react change color of a single element with index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I just started learning react 2 days ago, and I am trying to change the color of a button on click. I have 2 buttons, each of them should change color when clicked, however, my code changes the color of both when I just click one. I read that I need to use an index somewhere, but I am not sure where or how to map the index. Any help will be much appreciated. here's my code:

```
let ash = "#959595";
let purple = "#8c52ff";

const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState(ash);

function handleColorChange(e) {
    const button = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
    const newButton = e.target.style.backgroundColor;

    const newColor = buttonColor === ash ? purple : ash;
    setButtonColor(newColor);
}

return (
    <div>
        <button
            className="days-btn"
            style={{ backgroundColor: buttonColor }}
            color={buttonColor}
            onClick={handleColorChange}
        >
            M
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button
            className="days-btn"
            style={{ backgroundColor: buttonColor }}
            color={buttonColor}
            onClick={handleColorChange}
        >
            T
        </button>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: The problem is that both of your buttons rely on the same state `buttonColor`, hence they behave equally. You should solve this either by separating state variables or have an object in state with a unique property for each button.

Comment: buttonColor is applied to both buttons that's why property is getting applied to both button, create two different states for two different buttons.

Comment: does it mean that I will have to write the function twice with different var names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add color on every button Click React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69171675/add-color-on-every-button-click-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is two buttons share the same state. You can keep the color-changing logic in a  separate `Button` component. So `Button`s can change their color independently.

```
import { useState } from "react";

let ash = "#959595";
let purple = "#8c52ff";

const Button = ({ buttonText }) => {
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState(ash);

  function handleColorChange(e) {
    const newColor = buttonColor === ash ? purple : ash;
    setButtonColor(newColor);
  }

  return (
    <button
      className="days-btn"
      style={{ backgroundColor: buttonColor }}
      color={buttonColor}
      onClick={handleColorChange}
    >
      {buttonText}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

In your other component create two buttons giving any props as you need.

```
import Button from "./Button";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button buttonText="M" />
      <Button buttonText="T" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-lake-y205e?file=/src/Button.js)

Comment: I understand, but in your snippet, the buttons don't change back to their original color when clicked again. If a purple button is clicked, it should go back to being ash

Comment: I have fixed it now. please check